# WFS-T demo with local Geoserver not responding

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, wfs, wfs-t

i have installed the geoserver in my local system

and i tried to run the example code from openlayers the code as below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <title>OpenLayers WFS Protocol with Filter</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost:8080/openlayers/theme/default/style.css" type="text/css">
    <script src="http://localhost:8080/openlayers/lib/OpenLayers.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3&amp;sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var map, wfs;
       // OpenLayers.ProxyHost = "http://localhost:8080/openlayer/proxy.jsp?targetUrl=";
        var DeleteFeature = OpenLayers.Class(OpenLayers.Control, {
            initialize: function(layer, options) {
                OpenLayers.Control.prototype.initialize.apply(this, [options]);
                this.layer = layer;
                this.handler = new OpenLayers.Handler.Feature(
                        this, layer, {click: this.clickFeature}
                );
            },
            clickFeature: function(feature) {
                // if feature doesn't have a fid, destroy it
                if(feature.fid == undefined) {
                    this.layer.destroyFeatures([feature]);
                } else {
                    feature.state = OpenLayers.State.DELETE;
                    this.layer.events.triggerEvent("afterfeaturemodified",
                            {feature: feature});
                    feature.renderIntent = "select";
                    this.layer.drawFeature(feature);
                }
            },
            setMap: function(map) {
                this.handler.setMap(map);
                OpenLayers.Control.prototype.setMap.apply(this, arguments);
            },
            CLASS_NAME: "OpenLayers.Control.DeleteFeature"
        });

        function init() {

            var extent = new OpenLayers.Bounds(
                    -11593508, 5509847, -11505759, 5557774
            );


            map = new OpenLayers.Map('map', {
                projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"),
                displayProjection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
                restrictedExtent: extent,
                controls: [
                    new OpenLayers.Control.PanZoom(),
                    new OpenLayers.Control.Navigation()
                ]
            });
            var gphy = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google(
                    "Google Physical",
                    {type: google.maps.MapTypeId.PHYSICAL, sphericalMercator: true}
            );

            var saveStrategy = new OpenLayers.Strategy.Save();

            wfs = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Editable Features", {
                strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.BBOX(), saveStrategy],
                projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
                protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS({
                    version: "1.1.0",
                    srsName: "EPSG:4326",
                    url: "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs",
                    featureNS :  "http://opengeo.org",
                    featureType: "restricted",
                    geometryName: "the_geom",
                    schema: "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs/DescribeFeatureType?version=1.1.0&typename=saartha:pointlayer"
                })
            });

            map.addLayers([gphy, wfs]);

            var panel = new OpenLayers.Control.Panel({
                displayClass: 'customEditingToolbar',
                allowDepress: true
            });

            var draw = new OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature(
                    wfs, OpenLayers.Handler.Point,
                    {
                        title: "Draw Feature",
                        displayClass: "olControlDrawFeaturePolygon",
                        multi: true
                    }
            );

            var edit = new OpenLayers.Control.ModifyFeature(wfs, {
                title: "Modify Feature",
                displayClass: "olControlModifyFeature"
            });

            var del = new DeleteFeature(wfs, {title: "Delete Feature"});

            var save = new OpenLayers.Control.Button({
                title: "Save Changes",
                trigger: function() {
                    if(edit.feature) {
                        edit.selectControl.unselectAll();
                    }
                    saveStrategy.save();
                },
                displayClass: "olControlSaveFeatures"
            });

            panel.addControls([save, del, edit, draw]);
            map.addControl(panel);
            map.zoomToExtent(extent, true);
        }

    </script>
    <style>
        html,body,#map{
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
        }


        .customEditingToolbar {
            float: right;
            right: 0px;
            height: 30px;
        }
        .customEditingToolbar div {
            float: right;
            margin: 5px;
            width: 24px;
            height: 24px;
        }
        .olControlNavigationItemActive {
            background-image: url("http://localhost:8080/openlayers/theme/default/img/editing_tool_bar.png");
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-position: -103px -23px;
        }
        .olControlNavigationItemInactive {
            background-image: url("http://localhost:8080/openlayers/theme/default/img/editing_tool_bar.png");
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-position: -103px -0px;
        }
        .olControlDrawFeaturePolygonItemInactive {
            background-image: url("http://localhost:8080/openlayers/theme/default/img/editing_tool_bar.png");
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-position: -26px 0px;
        }
        .olControlDrawFeaturePolygonItemActive {
            background-image: url("http://localhost:8080/openlayers/theme/default/img/editing_tool_bar.png");
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-position: -26px -23px ;
        }
        .olControlModifyFeatureItemActive {
            background-image: url("http://localhost:8080/openlayers/theme/default/img/move_feature_on.png");
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-position: 0px 1px;
        }
        .olControlModifyFeatureItemInactive {
            background-image: url("http://localhost:8080/openlayers/theme/default/img/move_feature_off.png");
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-position: 0px 1px;
        }
        .olControlDeleteFeatureItemActive {
            background-image: url("http://localhost:8080/openlayers/theme/default/img/remove_point_on.png");
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-position: 0px 1px;
        }
        .olControlDeleteFeatureItemInactive {
            background-image: url("http://localhost:8080/openlayers/theme/default/img/remove_point_off.png");
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-position: 0px 1px;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body onload="init()">

<div id="map"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

When i click on the save the request to geoserver is in pending for more then 10 min

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The problem is related to your schema. OpenLayers uses it in xsi:schemaLocation, and It seems GeoServer doesn't like it. See http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GEOS-6406.